# Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module... during DigitalOcean App Platform deployment

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, module, digital-ocean

I'm trying to deploy my node js backend to DigitalOcean with their App Platform with Github.

I tried many things but still don't work yet.

I get this error :
[image: Error]

I suppose it can ben because of type module from es6 but localy it work perfectly fine...
Every files are in good folders in my repo in Github so I don't understand why I still get this error...

And this error occur with others controllers/models too, changing each deployment...

This is my first true deployment for a customer and I really need help :-)

Thanks !